# CFG for reverse polish notation

Tags: theory, context-free-grammar, prefix-operator

I need to create a CFG for reverse polish notation with operators +-*/ and then write out the right derivation and create an abstract syntax tree.

I understand how to create the derivation and the syntax tree but I don't really understand how to create a CFG given a set of rules.
I've done a lot of research online and I am only able to find out how to use a CFG but not how to create one with a given set of rules.

If someone could point me in the right direction or explain a different example of this that would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are referring to with a given set of rules...? Isn't the grammar just

```
X -> X X o
X -> n
```

Where `o` is an operator and `n` a number?

Comment: set of rules meaning the definition of postfix notation

I'm not really sure how you're getting that as the grammar is my question. Is that just saying that you apply o to X and X where X can be some value n?
Also, is there no reason to create a distinction between the two different Xs in the first line because they could be two different numbers or is it sufficient to just say X?

Comment: If you add the definition to postfix notation to your question, it might be easier to explain how to derive the corresponding grammar rules. In CFGs, the same symbols are used where they can be replaced the same way.

Comment: thanks I actually figured it out just now with my prof and your response above was correct!